# How to safely store strings (i.e. password) in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, string, security

I'm working on a wxWidgets GUI application that allows the user to upload files to an FTP server and a pair of username/password is required to access the FTP server.

As far as I know, STL strings or even char* strings are visible to end user even the program is compiled already, using hex editors or maybe string extractors like [Sysinternals String Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439).

So, is there a safe/secure way to store sensitive informations inside a C++ application?

PS. I cannot use .NET for this application.

Comment: Perhaps you should allow anonymous FTP on the server, so you can put nonsense strings in the app, and monitor the server to remove crap added by warez people, but at least know you don't have a real id and password in the wild? Failing that, make sure this ID and password have essentially no privileges other than putting things into that one FTP location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually independent of the programming language used.

FTP is a protocol that transfers its password in plain text. No amount of obfuscation will change that, and an attacker can easily intercept the password as it is transmitted.

And no amount of obfuscation, no matter the protocol used, will change the fact that your *application* has to be able to *decode* that password. Any attacker with access to the application binary can reverse-engineer that decoding, yielding the password.

Once you start looking at *secure* protocols (like SFTP), you also get the infrastructure for *secure* authentication (e.g. public/private key) when looking at automated access.

Even then you are placing the responsibility of not making that key file accessable to anyone else on the file system, which - depending on the operating system and overall setup - might not be enough.

But since we're talking about an *interactive* application, the simplest way is to not make the authentication automatic at all, but to query the user for username and password. After all, he should know, shouldn't he?

**Edit:** Extending on the excellent comment by Kate Gregory, in case that users share a common "technical" (or anonymous) account accessing your server, files uploaded by your app should not be visible on the server before some kind of filtering was done by you. The common way to do this is having an "upload" directory where files can be uploaded to, but not be downloaded from. If you do not take these precautions, people will use your FTP server as turntable for all kind of illegal file sharing, and *you* will be the one held legally responsible for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that is possible at all, and if, than not easy. If the password is embedded and your program can read it, everybody with enough knowledge should be able to do.

You can improve security against lowlevel attempts (like hexeditor etc.) by encrypting or obfuscating (eg two passwords which generate the real password by XOR at runtime and only at the moment you need it).

But this is no protection against serious attacks by experienced people, which might decompile you program or debug it (well, there are ways to detect that, but it's like cold-war - mutual arms race of debugging-techniques against runtime-detection of these).

edit: If one knows an good way with an acceptable amount of work to protect the data (in c++ and without gigantic and/or expensive frameworks), please correct me. I would be interested in that information.

Comment: use something like [xxtea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA) to encrypt in the code (this is a small symmetrical cypher). But as you say this is easy to defeat as you will need the key in the code.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that you cannot defend against someone who decompiles your code and figures out what you're doing, you can obscure the password a little bit so that it isn't in plain text inside the code. You don't need to do a true encryption, just anything where you know the secret. For example, reverse it, rot13 it, or interleave two literal strings such as "pswr" and "asod". Or use individual character variables (that are not initialized all together in the same place) and use numbers to set them (ascii) rather than having 'a' in your code.

In your place, I would feel that snooping the traffic to the FTP server is less work than decompiling your app and reading what the code does with the literal strings. You only need to defeat the person who opens the hex and sees the strings that are easily recognized as an ID and password. A littel obscuring will go a long way in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, storing a password is never really save but if you insist you can use [cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score -3):

Just a raw idea for you to consider.

Calculate the md5 or SHA-2 of your password and store it in the executable.

Then do the same for input username/password and compare with stored value.

Simple and straightforward.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Comment: He's trying to authenticate his application against the FTP server. Having a hash of the password locally doesn't help.

Comment: read the title of the question: How to safely store strings (ie. password) in a C++ application?
thx for -1

Comment: The -1 was not by me. And sometimes it helps to read the question too, not only the title. *Now* I give you a -1. ;-)

Comment: If the password appears in the package for FTP there is no need to put any effort to encrypt the password) So I agree with your answer :) But sometimes people are doing search here and looking into title of the questions so it is not the best answer I believe, although it appears to be so by now :)

Comment: Again, the purpose of this site is giving answer to *questions*, not answering one's interpretation of the *title*. You answered a question that is not there.